# React component doesn't render in Production Build (works in Dev...)

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, rendering, production

I have a component that takes a `beerId` from the url params, fetches a product and render.
If you refresh, renders again, no problem - in DEV MODE.

In production, the component only works ONCE, when you get to it by clicking though to this page from another Browser page. If you refresh, it's a 404. What's wrong here?

NOTE: I am deploying with Github Pages.

Component:

```js
const BeerDetails = () => {
  
  const [selectBeerData, setSelectBeerData] = useState({
    // omit default state values
  })
  
  // get id from URL
  const params = useParams();
  const { beerId } = params;
  
  // some Redux stuff
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const currencySign = useSelector(state => state.search.currencySign);
  const currencyCode = useSelector(state => state.search.currencyCode);

  const { beer } = useFetch(beerId)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(beer) {
        const beerPricedInGBP = addPrice(beer)
        const beerWithCurrency = applyCurrency(beerPricedInGBP, currencyCode);
        const selectBeerData = getSelectedBeerDetails(beerWithCurrency);
        setSelectBeerData(selectBeerData)
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    } 
  }, [beer])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(beer) {
       const beerPricedInGBP = addPrice(beer) 
       const beerWithCurrency = applyCurrency(beerPricedInGBP, currencyCode);
       const selectBeerData = getSelectedBeerDetails(beerWithCurrency);
      setSelectBeerData(selectBeerData)
    }
  }, [currencyCode])

  const { name, image_url, abv, ibu, price, tagline, description } = selectBeerData;

  // return
```

Routes:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/punk-beer" component={Browse} />
            <Route path="/punk-beer/beers/:query" component={SearchResult} />
            <Route path="/punk-beer/basket" component={Basket} />
            <Route path="/punk-beer/beer-details/:beerId" component={BeerDetails} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Many thanks for looking at this folks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same issue, here is a comprehensive guide to fix it:

https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages

But it's not very easy. In the end, I deployed on Netlify instead of gh pages. It has the same problem re:client-side routing but it's waaaaay easier to fix. Here is all you need:

https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2020-06-27-how-deployment-services-make-client-side-routing-work

(scroll to the Netlify section)

Additional guides on the `netlify.toml` file and syntax:

https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/

https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#redirects

Good luck!